# Comparing a constant with an array(or multiple values.)

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to search zipcodes matchin in area of 25 miles.
lets say I got 10 zip codes from my function that holds true.

now I have my value in a variable like this:

```
$zip_res = A0A 1B0, A0A 1G0, ...
```

column name is postal_code.

How can I match all values at once with postal_code?
I can not use loop, I have to do it in one time.

any suggestions are welcome.

#### Edit

MySQL statement where $zip_res is used

```
$sql=   "SELECT distinct(p.id), p.extra FROM practitioner p INNER JOIN practitioner_category pc ON pc.practitioner_id = p.id AND pc.category_id = ";
$sql .= "'" .$this->category. "' ";
$sql .= "AND p.primary_postal_code in " .$zip_res. " WHERE 1 AND p.status = 1 ";
```

Comment: Something wrong with capital letters? And that does not look like valid MySQL to me...

Comment: This is not a MySQl query. It is how the data is arranged.

Comment: You have not demonstrated how any data is arranged. You have something called `$zip_res` that "equals" a bunch of characters; it makes no sense. What language is this really?

Comment: I agree this could be in more precise manner.
This MySQL. And these bunch of characters are zip codes (canadian format). I needed it to match it zip codes in my database.
by the way @cwallenpoole answered it to me, exactly what was required.

Comment: As I said, this is not valid MySQL. Can you demonstrate that code being used in a MySQL statement?

Comment: yes i can get u the working code.
i will edit my question and to it. by the way what will be the right way to share it? i m new, so it will be help.

Comment: @Tomalak have a look at my question, i edited it with MySQL query I am using with $zip_res

Comment: `$zip_res` is a PHP variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just looking for the `IN` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE POSTAL_CODE IN ($zip_res);
```

Just as a note, however, you need to be able to quote all of those items first. So you might do this before using the above query:

```
$zip_res = "'" . str_replace(',',"','",$zip_res) . "'";
```

Comment: Thanks alot! your 'Just as a note' was very useful. :)

Comment: This is PHP. Since when was this question about PHP...?

Comment: @Tomalak Based on the presence of a sigil (meaning it was likely either PHP or Perl), and the OP's other contributions to SO (referencing strtotime), it is not hard to guess that it was PHP.

Comment: @callenpoole: Guessing is irrelevant. The question did not specify PHP. I even asked for clarification and the OP responded "this is MySQL" :(

Comment: @Gangesh: Next time please be clear about the topic of your question.

Comment: @Tomalak I made the guess in an attempt to help. Unfortunately, the balance between "be specific" and "be helpful" is too fine a line.

Comment: @Tomalak This is a question about MySQL, but cwallenpoole made an extra attempt to it with giving a code that was useful before implementing that query. I guess he has worked on same kind of situation before. Anyways, I will be more specific in my questions next time.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use

```
select ... from ... where postal_code ALL($zip_res).
```

But I'm not sure because of in accordance to manual you should use subqueries.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html